# How can I get TotalPages in SSRS Report body?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is there any way to get total pages in ssrs report body? I tried different metods but could not get page number in the report body

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to do what you are asking.

The `Globals!TotalPages` value is only available once the report body has finished rendering, until then the server will not know the total number of pages in the report.
This is why an error is generated when you try and reference `TotalPages` in the report body. You will only be able to use this value in the header or footer.